# How to integrate with Snowflake after Kafka Enrichment stream

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowplow

I am new to the Snowplow framework, I'm able to send behavioural event using tracker to collector (via Kafka stream good event data able to produce on Kafka topics). Also, integrated with enrichments module write back to enriched Kafka output topic.

Able to run module independently now stuck with snowflake (**snowplow-snowflake-loader-5.6.1.jar**) integration with stream data can someone please help with step to follows (with config files)?

Below are the jar used to run the modules.

1. **snowplow-stream-collector-kafka-2.9.0.jar**
2. **snowplow-stream-enrich-kafka-3.8.0.jar**